# encrypt passwords in Laravel for users already created

Tags: laravel, mongodb, bcrypt

We found a bug in our API that allowed some users to be registered with plain password (login doesn't work for them though)

It wasn't encrypted like `bcrypt($password)` and saved in Mongodb using use Jenssegers\Mongodb package.

I found out how to select those users in Mongodb

```
db.getCollection('users').find({ 
    "$expr": { "$lt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$password" }, 11 ] } 
})
```

How can I do the same in `tinker` and update all those users' password and save it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Raw expressions](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/v3.6.0/README.md#raw-expressions) are injected directly in the query. It would be possible to write the query in PHP similar to this.

```
$users = User::whereRaw([
    '$expr' => ['$lt' => [['$strLenCP' => "$password"], 11 ]] 
])->get();
```

Check that results of running the query are correct, then run the following to update the documents.

> Make sure to test on a database copy before running on the live one.

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    User::where('_id', $user['_id'])
    ->update(
        ['password' => Hash::make($user['password'])]
    );
}
```

Or, get all users and perform the filtering in-memory.

```
$users = User::all();

$updateUsers = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if(mb_strlen($user->password, "UTF-8") < 11) {
        $updateUsers[] = $user; 
    }
}
```

Then update filtered users,

```
foreach($updateUsers as $user) {
    $user->password = bcrypt($user->password);
    $user->save();
}
```